# Laravel 5.2: Creating a custom route function - extending route

Tags: php, laravel, routes, extending

So basically, I want to create my own `Route::custom` function.

This is because I've been using the same groups and middleware for several routes throughout the site (I'm also using modules with subdomains, so we're talking about saving 5-6 lines of code per route)

All I want is for `Route::custom` to just call two or three other Route functions. For example:

`Route::Module('forum')` to be replaced with

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web','auth'], 'domain' => 'forum.' . env('SITE_DOMAIN', 'example.com')], function () {
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'permission:access.forum'], function () {
        Route::get('/', function () {
            return view('forum::forum.index');
        })->name("forum.index");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extends laravel default facade then add static method as you want.
**Notice:** You must replace route facade config in `config/app.php` to your custom facade class.
[Example here](https://github.com/hoangtv2101/laravel-web-router)

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand properly question 1. But for question 2, try this:

Go to app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php. Look for the function mapWebRoutes(). The line

```
require base_path('routes/web.php');
```

Duplicate it and change so you now have :

```
require base_path('routes/web.php');
require base_path('app/User/route.user.php');
require base_path('app/Whatever/route.whatever.php');
```

I guess this will resolve for your problem